# jQuery - :not :else?

Tags: jquery, click, show

Apologies about the poor title but I couldn't think of an easy way to describe this issue. I'm using the following simple jQuery:-

```
$("a:not(.havechild)").click(function () {
    $('#nowloading').show();
});
```

Whenever any link on a page is clicked it shows a "Now Loading" spinner, unless the link being clicked uses the class "havechild", which opens another level of an accordian menu.

My problem is that the sub-levels of the accordian menu also use the "havechild" class but do not trigger the accordian (purposely), but this also means that the loading spinner isn't being shown when I'd like it to.

I'm sure this is possible but not sure how to go about it. Essentially I need something like this:-

```
$("a:not(.havechild):else(.havechild .havechild)").click(function () {
    $('#nowloading').show();
});
```

Is this possible? :)

Comment: Please post an example of your HTML and create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. If you have problems with certain behavior, it is easier for us to help you if we can actually see the behavior. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to write an else condition, use an "and" (the comma in the selector):

```
$("a:not(.havechild), a.havechild a.havechild").click(function () {
    $('#nowloading').show();
});
```

This will select both:

- all anchor elements which do not have the class `havechild`
- all anchor elements which have the class `havechild` and also have an ancestor anchor element with the class `havechild`

Comment: I believe this does what you intended. Please let me know if it doesn't and take Felix Kling's advice, because your question is not entirely clear.